# ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python

I am trying to import NumPy in the IPython 3 terminal, and receiving the following error.

```
In [16]: import numpy as np
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: ...because you haven't installed `numpy`?

Comment: pls send some reference to install numpy and scipy and pandas

Comment: @naveen I hate to sound rude, but please just use a search engine.

Comment: i want to work with ipython command prompt so in that i am trying to import the numpy then getting below error:

Comment: In [16]: import numpy as np
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: i am the new for python so strucking at that starting point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download pip:

https://packaging.python.org/installing/

run `python get-pip.py` after downloading the file from the instructions. Then:

```
pip install numpy scipy pandas
```

Then you should be good to go.